# Setting Package-Wide MSRs for Uncore Frequency and Cache Allocation Technology

Tags: x86, x86-64, intel, cpu-architecture, msr

I am trying to set way masks for different class of service (COS) on an Intel Xeon processor.
I am using the following command to make COS0 use all but the last four cache ways:

```
sudo wrmsr 0xc90 0x7f0
```

If I `rdmsr` the `0xc90` on processor 0 I find that the mask has been applied correctly. The [technical documentation](https://sudo%20wrmsr%20-p%201%200xc90%200x7f0) states that the register `0xc90` is a package wide register. However, when I read the value of register `0xc90` from processor one as follows:

```
sudo rdmsr -p 1 0xc90
```

I find that the cache ways mask has not been applied to processor 1's MSR. I had similar outputs when setting uncore frequency my manipulating `0x620` which is also a package wide register.

My question is that since the register is supposed to be package-wide, do I need to set `0xc90` on each processor individually to make the package adhere to the required cache mask? Or are the package wide registers such as `0xc90` and `0x620` (the uncore frequency ratio register) only read from processor 0's MSRs and then applied to the whole package regardless of the value they hold in the rest of the processors?

I hope my question makes sense. I would be glad to provide any clarification. Thank you!

Comment: Is your machine multi-socket?  If so, the set of cores on each socket is a separate package.  (If not, then all your cores are part of the same package.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh damn! I thought I had turned off the second socket. Thank you so much for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a stupid mistake. I thought I had turned off socket 1 while running the aforementioned commands. But in reality I had not turned it off. So `rdmsr -p 1` was reading registers from socket 1 instead of socket 2. @PeterCorders's comment helped me realize that I had not turned off the second socket properly.